# How to apply the array of functions to array of corresponding arguments in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, I have an array of functions:
`[func1, func2, func3, func4]` and array of arguments `[arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]`. I need to apply func1 to arg1, func2 to arg2 etc.

What is the best way to do this? Of course, I can use simple loop to go through elements, but maybe more elegant way exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. I'd suggest using the [`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the functions, because then you can easily put their return values into another array:

```
const results = funcs.map((f, i) => f(args[i]))
```

In context:

```js
const funcs = [
  (a) => a * 2,
  (a) => a * 3,
  (a) => a * 4,
  (a) => a * 5
]
const args = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const results = funcs.map((f, i) => f(args[i]))

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's "elegant," but you can do

```
let results = functionArray.map((f, i) => f(arguments[i]))
```

This takes each function in your array, finds the associated argument `i`, and calls the function with that argument.

Comment: Well I think it's elegant, but then I came up with an identical solution so I'm biased. (Sorry, normally I would delete my answer upon realising somebody else posted the same thing first, but in this case I didn't notice your answer until after I took the time to add a working demo, so I'll leave you with an upvote instead.)

Comment: @nnnnnn No problem! Yours included multiple ways to accomplish it!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a library like Lodash, you can use [`_.zipWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zipWith), which iterates several arrays at once all in parallel, calling the provided function with the elements of the arrays.

```
const results = _.zipWith(funcs, args, (f, a) => f(a));
```

If you want a simple implementation of `zipWith` without importing the library, use:

```
const zipWith = (...arrays) => {
  const func = arrays.pop();
  return arrays[0].map((_, i) => func(...arrays.map(arr => arr[i])));
};
```

```js
const zipWith = (...arrays) => {
  const func = arrays.pop();
  return arrays[0].map((_, i) => func(...arrays.map(arr => arr[i])));
};

const funcs = [
  a => a * 2,
  a => a * 3,
  a => a * 4,
  a => a * 5
];
const args = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(zipWith(funcs, args, (f, a) => f(a)));
```